# Apply SASS files directory import to specific div

Tags: css, sass

My SASS file:

```
@import "path/to/a/special/style-set/*"

// Custom Styles
span
 color: #fff
```

My HTML:

```
<a href="index.html>Link</a>
<div id="special-link"><a href="index-special.html>I am special</a></div>
```

Question: How can I apply the imported style set from above to the div `special-link` only and not to any other divs on the page?

I thought that this is possible:

```
#special-link
 @import "path/to/a/special/style-set/*"
```

but that does not seem to work.

Comment: It is possible to nest imports in Sass as you describe, you must have another problem. Can you post the actual code which has the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Having ID in your Div would allows you only to style that specific div, actually you don't need to create and other stylesheet for that. But if you need to import that sass file then in your imported sass file you have to indicate the style for the id #special-link, then it should work.